# @VisibleForTesting in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, lint

I have added @VisibleForTesting on a public property in a Kotlin class and then used in where it shouldn't be allowed, yet my lint checks pass successfully. Should I avoid @VisibleForTesting in Kotlin? This is an Android project.

Comment: How are you running the lint check? Through Android Studio? Or the command line? Also could you provide the code that you use the annotation and where you expect the call to fail?

Comment: I run "./gradlew lint" in command line. I cannot share my code, but I accessed a public var with "@VisibleForTesting" in a viewmodel from a fragment, I expected the lint check to fail but it doesn't. If I do something similar i Java, the lint check fails as expected.

Comment: @MarkusK, I see that your quetion is pretty old, but I have meet the similar situation and I use `@get:VisibleForTesting` for read-only and `@set:VisibleForTesting` for read-and-write properties. Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

It appears to be a bug. I've opened up a [bug report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/140642032) describing the issue. As far as I can tell, this only affects property access. A workaround in your case would be to use a regular function call.

Comment: regular function calls also present this bug